# The graphic in my project using turtle library doesn't appear on my screen

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle

fondo = turtle.Screen()

fondo.setup(width=500, height=500, startx=750, starty=300)

fondo.bgcolor("blue")
```

There's no `TypeError` or `NameError` in my project, so it's rare that this is happening. I'm using Pycharm for this project. Thank you

Comment: What "graphic" were you expecting to appear?  All this code should do is create a blank blue screen.

Comment: yes, but doesn't appear, any suggestions?

Comment: Does [Python Turtle Graphics Window only Opens Briefly then Closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018243/python-turtle-graphics-window-only-opens-briefly-then-closes) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably does appear, but very quickly closes again.  You didn't transfer control to the event handler so the program started and then immediately quit.  Add a `mainloop()` at the end to transfer control:

```
import turtle

fondo = turtle.Screen()

fondo.setup(width=500, height=500, startx=750, starty=300)

fondo.bgcolor("blue")

# the rest of your code goes here

fondo.mainloop()
```

This is true for standard Python/turtle, under PyCharm, things might work differently.

Answer (score 1):

it work fine for me I run the script on my phone and it executed with no error. Could you check if you have installed a python compiler, cuz pycharm is just an ide.

You need compiler to run high level programming languages eg python, c++, java but you can run assembly on any device, c programming languages can run on windows also.