# Turtle screen closes almost immediately after opening

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I  writed some code from a python book and the book shows that if you run the code there will be no problem

but when I ran the code there was a problem

This is my code:

```
import turtle
import time

turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.pencolor("white")
turtle.turtlesize(2,2,2)

def ileri():
    turtle.fd(5)
def geri():
    turtle.backward(5)
def sag():
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.fd(5)
    turtle.left(90)
def sol():
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(5)
    turtle.right(90)
def sagdon():
    turtle.right(10)
def soldon():
    turtle.left(10)
def siyah():
    turtle.pencolor("black")
def yesil():
    turtle.pencolor("green")
def acikyesil():
    turtle.pencolor("lightgreen")
def mavi():
    turtle.pencolor("blue")
def acikmavi():
    turtle.pencolor("lightblue")
def sari():
    turtle.pencolor("yellow")
def kirmizigul():
    turtle.pencolor("red")

turtle.onkeypress(ileri, "w" or "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(geri, "s" or "Down")
turtle.onkeypress(sag, "d")
turtle.onkeypress(sol, "a")
turtle.onkeypress(sagdon, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(soldon, "Left")
turtle.onkeypress(siyah, "0")
turtle.onkeypress(yesil, "1")
turtle.onkeypress(acikyesil, "2")
turtle.onkeypress(mavi, "3")
turtle.onkeypress(acikmavi, "4")
turtle.onkeypress(sari, "5")
turtle.onkeypress(kirmizigul, "6")
turtle.listen()
```

when I try to run this game every hecking time a screen opens for like 0.1 second and closes

if you try to help it will be so good for me

I was expecting the screen was going to be remain open because it was in the books image but I was not expecting to see the screen for just 0.1 seconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle Graphics Window only Opens Briefly then Closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018243/python-turtle-graphics-window-only-opens-briefly-then-closes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234798/turtle-graphics-how-do-i-control-when-the-window-closes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i believe this is what you tried to do all you had to do is import screen and set the screen setup and update it:

```
import turtle
from turtle import  Screen
import time

turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.pencolor("white")
turtle.turtlesize(2,2,2)

screen= Screen()
screen.setup(600,600)

def ileri():
    turtle.fd(5)
def geri():
    turtle.backward(5)
def sag():
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.fd(5)
    turtle.left(90)
def sol():
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(5)
    turtle.right(90)
def sagdon():
    turtle.right(10)
def soldon():
    turtle.left(10)
def siyah():
    turtle.pencolor("black")
def yesil():
    turtle.pencolor("green")
def acikyesil():
    turtle.pencolor("lightgreen")
def mavi():
    turtle.pencolor("blue")
def acikmavi():
    turtle.pencolor("lightblue")
def sari():
    turtle.pencolor("yellow")
def kirmizigul():
    turtle.pencolor("red")
while(True):
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.07)
    turtle.onkeypress(ileri, "w" or "Up")
    turtle.onkeypress(geri, "s" or "Down")
    turtle.onkeypress(sag, "d")
    turtle.onkeypress(sol, "a")
    turtle.onkeypress(sagdon, "Right")
    turtle.onkeypress(soldon, "Left")
    turtle.onkeypress(siyah, "0")
    turtle.onkeypress(yesil, "1")
    turtle.onkeypress(acikyesil, "2")
    turtle.onkeypress(mavi, "3")
    turtle.onkeypress(acikmavi, "4")
    turtle.onkeypress(sari, "5")
    turtle.onkeypress(kirmizigul, "6")
    turtle.listen()
    screen.exitonclick()
```

hope it was usefull to you and goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `turtle.done()` at the end of your code and the window will stay until you close it yourself.

Comment: This time It doesn't detect my keyboard. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

The official python wiki page for [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop) clearly states that:

> (turtle.mainloop) *Must* be the last statement in a turtle graphics program. Must not be used if a script is run from within IDLE in `-n` mode (No subprocess) - for interactive use of turtle graphics.

Since your program lacks a call to the `mainloop` function, it closes as soon as it is runs. All you have to do is add a

```py
turtle.mainloop()
turtle.done()
```

at the end of your program.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It works but this time it doesn't detect my keybord. But thank you so much for your help